# Adding a Vacuum Tube library to OrCAD CAPTURE

Tags: orcad

**Introduction**

I wanted to mess with Vacuum Tubes and learn from old electronics to show my granpa how they worked, specially radio (AM and FM). I downloaded a library of vacuum tubes but could not install it properly or i am missing something.

I am using OrCAD Capture 16.6-2015 Lite

**How did i get to the problem?**

I downloaded the RAR file containing a .lib and .OLB which i copy pasted into the next directories.

.lib at C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.6_Lite\tools\pspice\library

and

.OLB at C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.6_Lite\tools\capture\library

**Where is the problem?**

When i run the simulation it jumps into this error:

ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit 12AT7 used by X_VL1 is undefined

That means it can not reach the library or some other file? I have read another question about the same problem but still could not solve the thing.

**Extra**

Here is a pic of the schematic if someone is interested of the FM radio with vacuum tubes.

[image]

PD: I know the values are not correct or adequate, it was a test to see if it could simulate and i am open to improvements if it a simple change i can understand.

Comment: Have you checked if the pins from the symbol match the ones described in the model?

Comment: i have checked that with every tube i get the same error.

Comment: I have no idea how it works with OrCAD, but when I wanted to simulate a design I did on a vacuum tube amplifier I used LTSpice with models from this website: http://www.duncanamps.com/spice.html

Comment: It's likely that it's a symbol library that doesn't have models associated with the parts. You need models to run simulations.

Comment: How i do the model, Andy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead download a free version of circuitmaker 2000 here: http://getintopc.com/softwares/simulators/circuit-maker-2000-free-download/

Then get these tube spice models that have been written for audio enthusiasts here and install them into the program which is quite easy.

http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/tubes-valves/84715-triode-spice-models-circuit-maker.html

Comment: The initial thought was to use them inside the software i said before, not just audio.